# where is the /models folder in the eagle directory?

Tags: eaglecad, model

I am reading the EAGLE schematic to spice model tutorial here: https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/blog/spice-simulation-part-5-schematic-spice-mapping/

I got stuck on the section of loading a model from your computer:

"... In this case, we don’t need to go searching the web for a diode model. The Models directory in EAGLE already has what we need. ...."

where is the "/models" directory? I cant find it anywhere! please help.

Comment: I searched for `DMOD.mdl` and on my machine it's found in: `C:\Program Files\EAGLE 9.6.2\examples\spice\examples`